# How to filter data that is far away from an arbitrary line

Tags: correlation

I have a made-up data that looks like below image. How do I filter out datapoints that are far away from the orange line and keep the ones that are near? The orange line starts from max(Y) to max(X).

I need to achieve a psuedo negatively-correlated data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate negatively correlated data, it is easier to have some generative model instead of rejection sampling. In other words, we still use a linear model generator, but set the coefficient to a negative number.

Here is an example

- Sample $X$ from uniform distribution
- Calculate $Y_0$ from $X$ by using some negative coefficient, such as $Y_0=-0.5*X$
- Add some noise, for example, let $Y =Y_0 + \epsilon$

In R, it can be

```
set.seed(0)
a = 0
b = -0.5

x=runif(100)
y0=a + b*x
y=y0+rnorm(100)*0.1
plot(x,y)
abline(a,b)
```

[image]

Comment: very clear! thank you very much and will apply this strategy instead